# Where can I find a longitudinal study with a binary response?

Tags: statistics, reference-request, data-analysis

I've spent the last couple of months trying to find real data (not simulated) of a longitudinal study, but I can't seem to find one. Any topic and time frame is fine, but the dependent variable must be binary, and a few covariables are also desirable. I appreciate any help immensely!

Comment: Whether the patient is still living is a binary response.

Answer (score 1):

Could this work for you?

[A Longitudinal Study of Social Media Privacy Behavior](http://search.arxiv.org:8081/paper.jsp?r=1103.3174&qid=13717744756799a_nCnN_-1430150761&qs=longitudinal%20study)

It seems that this is indeed a longitudinal study involving several binary variables.  Click "pdf only" in the upper right-hand corner to see the paper.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at it!